# What's the correct return type for a TypeScript HOC being used as a decorator?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, higher-order-components

I'm trying to write a simple HOC in TypeScript and am getting confused about what the return type should be. The HOC looks like this:

```
export const requiresUser = <P extends object>(Component: React.ComponentType<P>) =>
  class RequiresUser extends React.Component<P> {
    componentDidMount() {
      console.log("requires user")
    }

    render() {
      return <Component {...this.props} />
    }
  }
```

If I then use it in a component such as this:

```
@requiresUser
export class DashboardPage extends React.Component<{}> {

  someFunction = () => {
    console.log("hi")
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        DashboardPage
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The compiler is sad because of the `someFunction` function. If I remove that function, it's all cool and happy because I guess it all matches nicely without having to explicitly set anything. Here's the error when the component includes `someFunction`:

```
(11, 1): Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression.
  Type 'typeof RequiresUser' is not assignable to type 'typeof DashboardPage'.
    Type 'requiresUser<{}>.RequiresUser' is not assignable to type 'DashboardPage'.
      Property 'someFunction' is missing in type 'requiresUser<{}>.RequiresUser'.
```

So my question is, what should the return type of the HOC be to allow for components which use it to define whatever functions they want? Returning `any` makes it work, but it feels like cheating..

Answer (score 1):

Seems like typescript does not support type mutation(since the decorated component is different from the original component) in decorator right now.

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881

Work around:

```js
export const requiresUser = <
  P,
  T extends { new (props: P): React.Component<P> }
>(
  Component: T
): T => {
  class RequiresUser extends React.Component<P> {
    componentDidMount() {
      console.log("requires user");
    }

    render() {
      return <Component {...this.props} />;
    }
  }
  return RequiresUser as T;
};
```